# Migrate data from a data only postgresql docker volume

Tags: postgresql, docker, backup, postgis

I have a data only postgresql container

`docker create -v /var/lib/postgresql/data --name bevdata mdillon/postgis /bin/true`

I have a running Postgis container

`docker run --name bevaddress -e POSTGRES_USER=bevsu -e POSTGRES_DB=bevaddress -P -d --volumes-from bevdata mdillon/postgis`

I have made a backup of that database into the bavaddress container into directory `/var/lib/postgresql/backup`

I *think* this means that the backup data is in container bevaddress (the running process) and NOT the data only container `bevdata` which I think is good.

Now if I `docker pull mdillon/postgis` to a new version, how can I attach the folder `/var/lib/postgresql/backup` of container `bevaddress` so that a new instance and version of `mdillon/postgis` can access that folder to restore the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot. The file system in your running container only exists for the duration of the run. Without mounting a volume, you have no way to allow a second container access to the backup.

For future backups, you could create a second volume only container that mounts `/var/lib/postgresql/backup`.

Comment: That's the solution I also came up with. Unfortunaltey it forces you to think in advance to add that second backup volume the moment you issue docker run. Later on it seems either impossible to do so (no way to add volume by docker start). Adding volumes in advance for backup/migration tasks should be at least described as a good practice.